# Can't retrieve result from list of options

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a code that goes

```
String[] team_list = {"Alpha","Bravo","Charlie"};
ArrayList<Team> team = generate_team(arr, team_list);
```

Then my function:

```
public static ArrayList<Team> generate_orders(int[] arr, String[] teamName]) {
    ArrayList<Team> team_list = new ArrayList<Team>();
    String team;
    for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        team= team_list[i%team_list.length];
        Team o = new Team(teamName);
        team_list.add(o);
        System.out.println(team_list + "\n");   
     }
     return team_list;
}
```

But my results were:

```
Alpha
Alpha
Alpha
```

When I added:

```
System.out.print("k= "+ i%team_list.length)
```

I get back, `123`.

Why didn't `team_list.add(o)` get the value of `i%team_list.length` though?

Comment: You call `geneerate_team` but you show us `generate_orders`.

Comment: `team_list[i % team_list.length]` is not a way to access the `ArrayList`. Please, provide a compilable code.

Comment: You cannot pass `Team` from the `team_list`, which is `ArrayList<Team>` into a `String`.

Comment: So team_list is both a local and a global variable or at least with different scopes. You can help yourself by naming your variables better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile. Below won't compile as `team_list` is an `ArrayList<Team>` so `[]` operator makes no sense as it's only applicable to arrays:

```
team= team_list[i%team_list.length];`
```

In Java arrays start at 0 and you can take advantage of [enhanced for loop statement](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes) when iterating over an array:

```
public static List<Team> generateOrders(String[] teamNames) {
    List<Team> result = new ArrayList<Team>();
    for (String name : teamNames) {
        Team t = new Team(name);
        result.add(t);
    }
    return result;
}
```

or using streams:

```
public static List<Team> generateOrders(String[] teamNames) {
    return Arrays.stream(teamNames)
        .map(Team::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood how to work with arrays.

```
public static ArrayList<Team> generateTeams(String[] teamNames) {
    ArrayList<Team> result = new ArrayList<Team>();
    for(i = 0; i < teamNames.length(); i++){
        result.add(new Team(teamNames[i]);
     }
     return result;
}

String[] team_list = {"Alpha","Bravo","Charlie"};
ArrayList<Team> teams = generateTeams(team_list);
```